# Реструктурирование массива хешей в единый хеш

Tags: ruby

Есть массив хешей:

```
[
  {
    :MessageIdentifier=>"LDM",
    :AirlineCode=>"U6",
    :FlightNumber=>"2951",
    :FlightDate=>"21"
  },
  {
    :Destination=>"GYD",
    :Male=>"48",
    :Female=>"50",
    :Children=>"12",
    :Infants=>"5"
  },
  {
    :Destination=>"EVN",
    :Male=>"43",
    :Female=>"50",
    :Children=>"9",
    :Infants=>"3"
  },
  {
    :Airport=>"GYD",
    :FRE=>"56",
    :POS=>"0",
    :Baggage=>"1682"
  }
]
```

Его нужно преобразовать в такой хеш:

```
{
  :MessageIdentifier=>"LDM",
  :AirlineCode=>"U6",
  :FlightNumber=>"2951",
  :FlightDate=>"21",
  :Airport=>"GYD",
  :FRE=>"56",
  :POS=>"0",
  :Baggage=>"1682",
  :Segments=>[
    {
      :Destination=>"GYD",
      :Male=>"48",
      :Female=>"50",
      :Children=>"12",
      :Infants=>"5"
    },
    {
      :Destination=>"EVN",
      :Male=>"43",
      :Female=>"50",
      :Children=>"9",
      :Infants=>"3"
    }
  ]
}
```

Задачу решил так:

```
segments_array = []
ldm_array.each do |line|
  @header = line         if line.key?(:MessageIdentifier)
  @header.merge!(line)   if line.key?(:Airport)
  segments_array << line if line.key?(:Destination)
end

@header.merge(Segments: segments_array)
```

Это работает, но это выглядит не красиво, плюс присутствует мутация.

Как можно переписать код, чтобы он был более простой и красивый?

Comment: Вы мутаций не бойтесь, просто изолируйте их в локальных значениях. Здесь вам почти удалось: у вас один из элементов массива на входе изменяется по ходу работы. А выглядит это вполне красиво, единообразно, без трюков. Не повредив очевидности и производительности кода, тут сложно что-то однозначно улучшить. Почти любое изменение будет довольно спорным.

Comment: в целом картина выглядит так https://gist.github.com/sanyco86/89ffed6f04380a9ff30bed11921699d0 буду признателен за любой совет по улучшению

Comment: @D-side правильно ли я понимаю, что Вы бы рекомендовали переделать метод parse на такой https://gist.github.com/sanyco86/ee508bcb9b756bdc145290ed94e268d2 ?

Comment: Да, что-то такое. Разве что последний мердж можно выкинуть, разместив ключ в исходном хэше сразу же (при условии, что в хэшах из массива он не попадётся). Всё.

Comment: Да я уже так и сделал, спасибо большое

Comment: Михаил, вы уже не первый год здесь вопросы задаете, а все путаете Ruby и Rails.

Comment: Путаница то в чем?